# Que aparezca solo sale price y no el regular price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo unos productos en *WordPress* utilizando *WooCommerce*. El plugin utiliza 2 precios: *regular price* y el *sale price*. Necesito que en alguno de esos productos me aparezcan los 2 precios, y en otros, solo el *sale price*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que si no se pone *regular price* y sí el *sale price*, no se muestra nada, y si se ponen los 2 price salen los 2.

Por medio de código creo que es la solución, pero no encuentro dónde puede estar. También me dieron una solución por medio de consultas en *PHPMyAdmin* pero no sé cómo ponerla:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS s
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS r
ON s.post_id = r.post_id
SET s.meta_value = r.meta_value
WHERE s.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND r.meta_key = '_regular_price'                        

UPDATE wp_postmeta AS s
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS r
ON s.post_id = r.post_id
SET s.meta_value = 'el valor que usted quiera'
WHERE s.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND r.meta_key = '_regular_price'
AND s.post_id = 'el id que ud encontro'
```

Comment: Juan, por favor, haz lo posible para incluir un __[mcve]__ que permita comprender qué estás haciendo para solucionar tu problema. De otra manera, tu pregunta resulta muy amplia y podría ser cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas modificar código, más bien, entender los conceptos:

Regular price: (Obligatorio) Es el precio normal del producto.
Sale price: (Opcional) Debe ser menor al precio regular porque se trata de una oferta.